# Adding FeatureCollection to a FeatureStore throwing AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, oracle, geotools, jts

This method is supposed to replace the features in the database with new features I pass to it.

```
 private static void replaceBoundaryShape(FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> dbFeatures) throws IOException, CQLException{
    FeatureStore<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fs = null;
    FeatureSchemaFactory factory  = FeatureSchemaFactory.init();

    DataStore geoStore = initDataStore();


    try{
        fs = (FeatureStore) geoStore.getFeatureSource(factory.getFieldFeatureSchema().getTypeName());
        fs.setTransaction(new DefaultTransaction());

        for(FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> iterator = dbFeatures.features(); iterator.hasNext();){
            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = iterator.next();
            Number fieldId = (Number) simpleFeature.getAttribute(FeatureSchemaFactory.FIELD_ID);
            Filter filter = createSearchByIdFilter(fieldId.longValue());
            fs.removeFeatures(filter);
        }
        fs.addFeatures(dbFeatures);
        fs.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(CQLException ex){
        throw new CQLException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this is where I create the feature collection passed to replace boundary shape

```
private static FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> createBoundaryFeatures(SimpleFeatureType dbSchema, Collection<FieldFeature> fields){
    List<SimpleFeature> result = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>(fields.size());
    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(dbSchema);

    for(FieldFeature f: fields){ 
        builder.set("BNDRS", f.getGeometries());
        builder.set("FIELD", f.getField());
        builder.set("FID", f.getFid());
        builder.set("GROWER", f.getGrower());
        builder.set("SIMPLIFIED_BNDRS", f.getSimplifiedGeometries());

        result.add(builder.buildFeature(null)); 
    }

    return DataUtilities.collection(result);
}
```

This is where I get my field features from a file path and a specified field:

```
private static Collection<FieldFeature> convertShpFile(String filePath, Field field) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    ShapefileDataStore source = new ShapefileDataStore(new File(filePath).toURL());

    Collection<FieldFeature> result = new LinkedList<FieldFeature>();

    DefaultQuery query = new DefaultQuery();
    query.setCoordinateSystemReproject(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

    FeatureCollection queryResult = source.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(query);
    FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> fi = queryResult.features();

    while(fi.hasNext()){
        SimpleFeature feature = fi.next();

        FieldFeature fieldFeature = new FieldFeature();

        Object defaultGeometry = feature.getDefaultGeometry();

        if(defaultGeometry instanceof Polygon){
            Polygon polygon = (Polygon) defaultGeometry;
            Polygon[] polygons = {polygon};

            defaultGeometry = geometryFactory.createMultiPolygon(polygons);
        }
       fieldFeature.setField(field.getId());
       fieldFeature.setGeometries(defaultGeometry);
       fieldFeature.setSimplifiedGeometries(GeoHelper.simplifyGeometry((Geometry) defaultGeometry));

       result.add(fieldFeature);
    }

    fi.close();
    source.dispose();

    return result;
}
```

The error occurs on the fs.addFeatures(dbFeatures) line of the replaceBoundaryShape method.

Removing features does not throw an error, but when I call the addFeatures function I receive this AbstractMethodError:
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.jdbc.PreparedStatementSQLDialect.setGeometryValue(Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;IILjava/lang/Class;Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;I)V

The error appears to be thrown when the features are being inserted into the JDBCDataStore

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.geotools.jdbc.PreparedStatementSQLDialect.setGeometryValue(Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;IILjava/lang/Class;Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;I)V
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertSQLPS(JDBCDataStore.java:4005)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1582)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1545)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.write(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:76)
at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:337)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeature(ContentFeatureStore.java:309)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeatures(ContentFeatureStore.java:263)
at com.conserviscorp.shape.upload.FieldDAO.replaceBoundaryShape(FieldDAO.java:146)
at com.conserviscorp.shape.upload.FieldDAO.updateFieldData(FieldDAO.java:116)
at com.conserviscorp.ui.MatchedFieldFrame$2.actionPerformed(MatchedFieldFrame.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: can you put the full stack trace in so we can see exactly what is throwing the exception

Comment: Added the stack trace

Comment: OK a little more info needed - what version of GT are you using and is it really an oracle DB you are talking to (going by your tag)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using the wrong version of geotools. When adding items to the dependencies I was using the 10-beta version in some parts, and the current version in other parts.

Comment: That is why we recommend using maven with a geotools.version property